# HTML validation in Bootstrap-modal fires onsubmit for each field when triggering submit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a function which triggers a form-submit on a Twitter Bootstrap modal button. When the form is invalid, the onsubmit event fires for each field that isn't valid.

The form has an hidden submit button to do the HTML validation and this hidden submit I trigger a click when I press the modal-button.

function:

```
$('#'+dialogId).on('click', '.btn-primary', function () {          
    var body = $(this).parent('.modal-footer').prev('.modal-body');
    var form = body.find('form');
        form.on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();    

            if(typeof form[0].checkValidity == 'function' && form[0].checkValidity() === true) {
                $.post($(form).attr('action'), form.serialize(), function (response) {
              // some other stuff      
                });
            }
        });               
    $('#'+buttonId).trigger('click');        
});
```

and the form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/app_dev.php/players/" method="post" name="appbundle_players">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-3 required" for="appbundle_players_firstname">Firstname</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control" pattern=".{2,}" maxlength="255" required="required" name="appbundle_players[firstname]" id="appbundle_players_firstname"></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-3 required" for="appbundle_players_lastname">Lastname</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control" pattern=".{2,}" maxlength="255" required="required" name="appbundle_players[lastname]" id="appbundle_players_lastname"></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-3 required" for="appbundle_players_passnr">Passnr</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" name="appbundle_players[passnr]" id="appbundle_players_passnr"></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-3 optional" for="appbundle_players_team">Team&nbsp;<span>(optional)</span></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9"><select class=" form-control" name="appbundle_players[team]" id="appbundle_players_team"><option value=""></option><optgroup label="Oberliga"><option value="8">Overclocks</option><option value="9">test</option><option selected="selected" value="13">fooop 2</option><option value="14">Jack old</option><option value="15">Spirit</option><option value="16">spitzendarter</option><option value="17">mittendrin</option><option value="20">Rock'n Rollers</option><option value="22">mittendrin</option><option value="23">fooop 2</option><option value="39">sdfsdfsdfsdf</option><option value="40">sdfsdfsdfsdf</option></optgroup><optgroup label="A-Liga"><option value="10">Hackstock</option><option value="11">DC Depp</option><option value="12">FooDarters</option><option value="19">ich bin der test</option></optgroup><optgroup label="B-Liga"><option value="21">B-Liga-Team 1</option><option value="41">Dart Breakers</option><option value="42">Foo Darters</option><option value="43">test</option></optgroup></select></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-sm-3 required" for="appbundle_players_active">Aktiv</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9"><select class=" form-control" name="appbundle_players[active]" id="appbundle_players_active"><option value="0">nein</option><option value="1">ja</option></select></div></div><div><button class="btn btn-default" style="display:none;" name="appbundle_players[save]" id="appbundle_players_save" type="submit">Save</button></div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Why does the function fire for each field that is not valid the ajax request?

Comment: What function fires for an invalid ajax request?

Comment: i called this code when i click on the button from bootstrap-modal. there is no invalid ajax-request, but when a field is invalid and i click agein on the save-button from the modal (now that field is valid), the "onsubmit" event was called as often as a field was invalid.